# use variable jquery inside PHP and inside jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, syntax

if u see this function `<?= input_txt('+order_id+') ?>`
have jquery variable but jquery send error

```
function order_status(type, order_id) {
    var value = type.value;

    var info = document.getElementById("cancel_id_" + order_id).value;
    document.getElementById("my_cancel_info").innerHTML = "Determine the reason for cancellation of the order number " + info;
    document.getElementById("cancelled_info").innerHTML = '<?= input_txt('+order_id+') ?>';




    if (value == 2) {
        $('#order_cancelled').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand the order in which PHP and javascript execute. PHP is rendered server-side, while javascript is rendered client-side. I suggest that you look into http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ where you can pass your javascript variable to a PHP script via AJAX and then return your result.